# Android Sqlite no such table error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have application on market. some people gave me this error;

no such table: UserInfo: , while compiling: SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'

but I have this code even;

```
    if(!this.dhn.isTableExists("UserInfo"))
    {
        updateDB();
    }
```

Update DB;

```
public void updateDB()
{
    try {
        InputStream myInput;

            myInput = getAssets().open("example.db");

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = "/data/data/ko.tb/databases/"
                + "example.db";

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        buffer = null;
        outFileName = null;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Table exist ;

```
public boolean isTableExists(String tableName) {

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

all error;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ko.tb/ko.tb.KOActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserInfo: , while compiling: SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserInfo: , while compiling: SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1442)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
at ko.tb.DataHelper.Guid(DataHelper.java:126)
at ko.tb.KOActivity.onCreate(KOActivity.java:202)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you copy paste exactly the error?

Comment: Did you confirm via adb that the database is correctly copied to your application's database area by `updateDB()`? Is the application package listed in the manifest `ko.tb`? Did you try using `getDatabasePath("example.db")` instead of constructing the path by hand?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I just tried for you clearly. all steps works fine what I tested is > made a copy db without UserInfo, push to adb then istableexist gave me false then made copy and tried to get guid works fine. but somepeople have difficulty, I dont know how to fix :( I think one of guy has Htc sensation. and I have 3 reports in couple hours thats all I know

Comment: The syntax of that error message is very suspicious. There seem to be extra characters (`: ,`) in the table name. Is there a path through your code where the table name might get corrupted?

Comment: @Ted Hopp just checked google if there is error-wording differance but looks same. for ex; sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CityType: , while compiling: select cityName from CityType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using multiple providers [this link should help](http://devserghini.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-sqliteopenhelper-and-multiple.html). As stated in description:

> One of the issues you may run into when having mutiple
>   ContentProviders in your Android app is that you will notice that the
>   SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(db) is not called for each one of your
>   providers. Therefore, you will end up with a database missing several
>   tables.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem sometime back, As far as i can remember I changed the database version in my database helper class to resolve the issue (see example below, you can change the version from 1 to 2 etc.).

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "isbn text not null, title text not null, " 
        + "publisher text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```